# GoDaddy php.ini config

Tags: php, hosting, shared-hosting

I have tried to override godaddy `php.ini` file but it's gives `permission denied`

> I am not able to use `sudo`

I think that is because I have shared hosting

So i have just put `.user.ini` and `php5.ini` in the `/` and `/public_html` but still no effect.

I am teing to increase the php memeory limit

If someone have an idea to extend or override the php.ini for shared hosting

Comment: Have you contacted GoDaddy support?

Answer (score 0):

Reading in the [godaddy website](https://es.godaddy.com/community/cPanel-Hosting/Increase-php-memory-limit/td-p/43187) it looks like you have to create the ´user.ini inside the folder ´/public_html´  and not `/`

> To update your memory limit on our cPanel Hosting plans, you'll want
>   to upload or create a .user.ini file in the /public_html directory. In
>   that file, you'd enter the following code:
>
> memory_limit = XM
>
> You would substitute the amount of memory you want
>   in megabytes for the X in the statement above.  For example, if you
>   wanted 500 MB, then you'd have '500M' after the equal sign.

Comment: I already have put it there as well and i read the documentation but no changes

Comment: Did you also tried to modify the `memory_limit` from the Cpanel??